# Duplicate Debian dedicated server to a virtual machine

Tags: debian, backup, file-copy, file-transfer, duplicate

We have a dedicated bare metal debian 10 server which runs some applications which were very hard to setup. Now this server needs to be migrated to a KVM based virtual machine. My plan was instead of setting up those applications again (which will cost a lot of time and be a big hassle) to find a way to somehow transfer/duplicate all contents of the dedicated server into a KVM virtual machine.

My initial idea was to just create a tarball of the contents of all directories under `/` (except `/boot`) and to just paste them into the KVM and see what happens. Would that be a good idea?

I think using `dd` to copy the entire `sda` disk wouldn't be a good idea because some data could become inconsistent during the copying and because of the fact, that the disk is much larger (much less space is actually used) than the space on the target KVM host.

We have no physical access to the dedicated bare metal server.

Can anyone give me some good advise on how to get this job done? How can I "transform" a dedicated bare metal server into a virtual machine based on KVM?

Answer (score 1):

Something like Clonezilla will help here. Basically

1. Boot Clonezilla, so the live system's disks are not being used
2. Let it create a full image to some temporary media
3. At your convenience, copy the image across to your VM environment
4. Boot Clonezilla from a virtual USB attached to your clean VM
5. Let it restore the full image

At this point you've an exact copy, which while it won't be sufficient for the transition from Physical to Virtual, it will be a good start.

You'll need to boot the VM, possibly with a rescue disk such as SysrescueCD, and fix up name references to formerly physical devices such as disk device names, network cards, IP addresses, and anything else that's hardware specific.

It's not a trivial process, but it's certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

> ... and see what happens. Would that be a good idea?

Sure!  As long as you don't wipe the original disk before you succeed you have nothing (but time) to lose.

A few years ago I did this.  I took a bare-metal machine and `dd`'d the disk into a raw virtual disk.  I think I was able to boot this fine with QEMU/KVM.  Using `qemu-img` from the `qemu-utils` package, I was also able to convert the raw disk image into other formats.  It supports both `qcow2` and `qed` used by KVM.

The only trick is doing this on a disk large enough to hold the image of the other disk.

I think I was doing this with Arch Linux at the time.  Not everything worked out of the box and I found that I needed to run `mkinitcpio -p linux` after booting to reconfigure the kernel for the new virtual hardware.  If this is needed on Debian, you'd probably use `update-initramfs -u`.

Sorry I don't remember any more specifics, but I know it's very possible and it is a lot easier than you may think.

These days we are using an ESXI hypervisor.  It comes with a super useful tool which can clone any network-attached *nix machine (bare-metal or not) into a VM.  All it needs is root access via ssh.

Answer (score 0):

- *which were very hard to setup*... I can already start with the warning that when this is the case it often means you'll have make at least some configuration-changes when moving everything to another server.
- *create a tarball of the contents* and *see what happens*... What will happen is problems, problems and more problems because it's a completely different architecture. Just to name 1 small thing as example (but obviously there is way, way more: names of the networkcards)
- What i would do **after** you ended up in this situation is to install the applications again, `rsync` the configurationfiles of the applications and make necessary changes again
- What i would **really** do is make sure you don't end up in this situation by running as much as possible in containers which are a lot easier to transfer between systems

Comment: They can't avoid ending up in this situation. It's what they've got

Comment: If containers are not an option you can still put as much as possible under some configuration management solution like Ansible

Comment: @N_dk, not retrospectively, they can't. Please read the question!

Comment: That is why i mention both the *after* and the *really* points, so that is not only helpful now but also in the future